# Calculating OT based on week/year between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

We pay twice a month.. pay periods are 1st-15th and 16th-EOM.  So the end of the pay period can end on any day.

We pay overtime based on Monday - Sunday over 40 hours.

If the pay period ends on Saturday and the employee has 47 hours we pay 7 hours on that check.. if the employee works on Sunday and now the total hours for the week is say 52.. we would pay 5 hours on their next check.. Right now it is a manual calculation process.

I am trying to wrap my head around how to write a query to get me that extra carry over ot..

Here is the output of the daily work total for my last pay period of 9/1/2019 to 9/15/2019 and since the 1st was on Sunday.. I need to calculate the OT for the week from 8/26/2019.  On this particular employee he works on call over the weekend.  He was paid 6.28 hours of overtime for the pay period 8/16/2019 to 8/31/2019, worked two additional hours on 9/1/2019 so that 2 hours of OT needs to be carried over to the 9/1/2019 to 9/15/2019 check.

`ID     HRS     WK  CDATE
STU02   8.16    35  2019-08-26 00:00:00.000
STU02   9.37    35  2019-08-27 00:00:00.000
STU02   9.07    35  2019-08-28 00:00:00.000
STU02   7.91    35  2019-08-29 00:00:00.000
STU02   9.12    35  2019-08-30 00:00:00.000
STU02   2.65    35  2019-08-31 00:00:00.000
STU02   2.00    35  2019-09-01 00:00:00.000
STU02   4.17    36  2019-09-02 00:00:00.000
STU02   9.40    36  2019-09-03 00:00:00.000
STU02   8.80    36  2019-09-04 00:00:00.000
STU02   8.90    36  2019-09-05 00:00:00.000
STU02   8.93    36  2019-09-06 00:00:00.000
STU02   2.56    36  2019-09-07 00:00:00.000
STU02   2.00    36  2019-09-08 00:00:00.000
STU02   8.66    37  2019-09-09 00:00:00.000
STU02   9.14    37  2019-09-10 00:00:00.000
STU02   9.07    37  2019-09-11 00:00:00.000
STU02   9.29    37  2019-09-12 00:00:00.000
STU02   9.94    37  2019-09-13 00:00:00.000
STU02   2.00    37  2019-09-15 00:00:00.000`

I appreciate any help this one has been driving me crazy with the many different things I have tried.

** UPDATE WITH TABLE & DATA **

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE]    Script Date: 9/18/2019 3:50:50 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE](
    [EMPLOYEE_ID] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [REG_TOTAL] [float] NULL,
    [WEEK_NUM] [int] NULL,
    [CDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [DAYOFWK] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 2, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-25 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 8.16, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 9.37, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-27 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 9.07, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-28 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 7.91, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 9.12, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 2.65, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 2, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 4.17, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-02 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 9.4, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-03 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 8.8, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 8.9, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 8.93, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-06 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 2.56, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-07 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 2, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-08 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 8.66, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-09 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 9.14, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 9.07, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-11 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 9.29, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-12 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DLI_TEST_DATE] ([EMPLOYEE_ID], [REG_TOTAL], [WEEK_NUM], [CDATE], [DAYOFWK]) VALUES (N'STU02', 9.94, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-13 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6)
GO
```

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: Your data creation script has 2019-09-01 as week 36 but I think it should be week 35.  Similar with 2019-09-08.

Comment: MS SQL 2012 for my Database.

Comment: Two things. First, does your firm strictly work daytime, or are there possibilities for shifts to cross over the midnight boundaries? Second, the only possible systematic way to approach this is to treat every week as a provisional calculation, which is then balanced in the following payroll.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery splits a given week's hours into the 2 different pay periods when applicable.
The where clause will include only weeks with overtime and that are split between 2 pay periods.
Select includes the math for overtime.

```
declare @DLI_TEST_DATA TABLE (
    [EMPLOYEE_ID] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [REG_TOTAL] [float] NULL,
    [WEEK_NUM] [int] NULL,
    [CDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [DAYOFWK] [int] NULL
) 

INSERT into @DLI_TEST_DATA
    VALUES (N'STU02', 2, 34, CAST(N'2019-08-25 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
        ,(N'STU02', 8.16, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2)
        ,(N'STU02', 9.37, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-27 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3)
        ,(N'STU02', 9.07, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-28 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4)
        ,(N'STU02', 7.91, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5)
        ,(N'STU02', 9.12, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6)
        ,(N'STU02', 2.65, 35, CAST(N'2019-08-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 7)
        ,(N'STU02', 2, 35, CAST(N'2019-09-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
        ,(N'STU02', 4.17, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-02 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2)
        ,(N'STU02', 9.4, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-03 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3)
        ,(N'STU02', 8.8, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4)
        ,(N'STU02', 8.9, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5)
        ,(N'STU02', 8.93, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-06 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6)
        ,(N'STU02', 2.56, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-07 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 7)
        ,(N'STU02', 2, 36, CAST(N'2019-09-08 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
        ,(N'STU02', 8.66, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-09 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2)
        ,(N'STU02', 9.14, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3)
        ,(N'STU02', 9.07, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-11 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4)
        ,(N'STU02', 9.29, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-12 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 5)
        ,(N'STU02', 9.94, 37, CAST(N'2019-09-13 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 6)

select WEEK_NUM,fullweek - (case when endfirstperiod+endsecondperiod <= 40 then 40.0 else endfirstperiod+endsecondperiod end) OvertimeCarriedOver
from (
    select week_num,sum(reg_total) fullweek
        ,sum(case when day(cdate) between 10 and 15 then reg_total else 0 end) endfirstperiod
        ,sum(case when day(cdate) between 16 and 21 then reg_total else 0 end) beginsecondperiod
        ,sum(case when day(cdate) between day(eomonth(cdate)) - 5 and day(eomonth(cdate)) then reg_total else 0 end) endsecondperiod
        ,sum(case when day(cdate) between 1 and 6 then reg_total else 0 end) beginfirstperiod
    from @DLI_TEST_DATA
    group by week_num
) basic
where fullweek > 40.0
    and beginfirstperiod+beginsecondperiod > 0
    and endfirstperiod+endsecondperiod > 0
order by week_num
```

Answer (score 0):

The core idea is to group everything into logical weeks and then look at dates where its associated pay period doesn't match with the first day of that week.

`carryover_max` is the hours from those days. Depending on when the 40th hour was worked that number might be too high. In the final output it is capped against the total overtime that week.

```
with weeks as (
    select week_start, week_end,
        case when sum(REG_TOTAL) > 40
             then sum(REG_TOTAL) - 40 else 0 end as overtime_total,
        case when sum(REG_TOTAL) > 40
             then sum(case when period <> week_period then REG_TOTAL else 0 end)
             else 0 end carryover_max
    from
        dbo.DLI_TEST_DATE cross apply (
            select
                dateadd(day, -datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, -1, cdate)) + 1, cdate)
        ) as v(week_start) cross apply (
            select
                dateadd(day, 6, week_start),
                case when datepart(day, week_start) <= 15 then 1 else 2 end,
                case when datepart(day, cdate) <= 15 then 1 else 2 end
        ) as v2(week_end, week_period, period)
    group by week_start, week_end
), periods as (
    select distinct period_start, period_end
    from
        dbo.DLI_TEST_DATE cross apply (
           select
                datefromparts(datepart(year, cdate), datepart(month, cdate),
                    case when datepart(day, cdate) <= 15 then 1 else 15 end),
                datefromparts(datepart(year, cdate), datepart(month, cdate),
                    case when datepart(day, cdate) <= 15 then 16 else datepart(day, eomonth(cdate)) end)
        ) v(period_start, period_end)
)
select period_start,
    sum(case when carryover_max > overtime_total then overtime_total else carryover_max end) as overtime_owed
from
    periods inner join
        weeks w on w.week_end >= period_start and w.week_end <= period_end
group by period_start;
```

https://rextester.com/TVXF30798

By the way, you really aren't going to want to use `float` for your datatype.

Since there was a question about week numbering I've just computed dates. This should prpbably work better with weeks across the New Year anyway. Also I did assume that your server settings have Sunday as the first day of the week when using `datepart(weekday...)`.

Comment: I would strongly recommend with a payroll problem like this, that the system be designed on similar principles to ordinary accountancy, where the inputting of worked hours immediately cause "debts" to be applied to a payroll account, and the processing of a payroll causes balancing "credits" to be applied against current debts. This will disconnect the payment of pay from the calculation of it.